# Java - See if a string contains any characters in it

Tags: java, regex, string, validation, character

The problem i'm having is when i check to see if the string contains any characters it only looks at the first character not the whole string. For instance I would like to be able to input "123abc" and the characters are recognized so it fails. I also need the string to be 11 characters long and since my program only works with 1 character it cannot go any further.

Here is my code so far:

```
public static int phoneNumber(int a)
{
   while (invalidinput)
            {
        phoneNumber[a] = myScanner.nextLine();

        if (phoneNumber[a].matches("[0-9+]") && phoneNumber[a].length() == 11 )
        {   
            System.out.println("Continue");
            invalidinput = false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid phone number: ");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

For instance why if i take away the checking to see the phoneNumber.length() it still only registers 1 character so if i enter "12345" it still fails. I can only enter "1" for the program to continue.

If someone could explain how this works to me that would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `regex` and `if condition` is wrong. Use it like this:

```
 if ( phoneNumber[a].matches("^[0-9]{11}$") ) {
    System.out.println("Continue");
    invalidinput = false;
 }
```

This will only allow `phoneNumber[a]` to be a 11 character long comprising only digits `0-9`

Comment: Further reading on boundary matchers for regular expressions in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Comment: @Patch: Just click on tick mark on top-left of my answer. Once clicked it will turn green.

Comment: Not a problem, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The + should be outside the set, or you could specifically try to match 11 digits like this: ^[0-9]{11}$ (the ^ and $ anchor the match to the start and end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the "+" after the "]" in your regex. So, you would change it to:

```
phoneNumber[a].matches("[0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using a for loop to go through each character?

Like:

```
public static int phoneNumber(int a)
{
   while (invalidinput)
            {

       int x = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < phoneNumber[a].length(); i++)
       {
        char c = phoneNumber[a].charAt(i);
        if(c.matches("[0-9+]")){
        x++;
       }


}
  if (x == phoneNumber[a].length){
    System.out.println("Continue");
    invalidinput = false;

        }
  else
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid phone number: ");
        }

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the legal characters in your phone numbers `0`..`9` and `+`?  If so, then you should use the regular expression `[0-9+]*`, which matches zero or more legal characters.  (If not, you probably meant `[0-9]+`.)  Also, you can use `[0-9+]{11}` instead of your explicit check for a length of 11.

The reason that your current code fails, is that [String#matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) does not check whether the regular expression matches *part* of the string, but whether it matches *all* of the string.  You can see this in the JavaDoc, which points you to [Matcher#matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29), which "Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern."